# Ordering heatmap rows by labRow

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I've got a heatmap from a FoldChange dataset (176x10) and labeled it using another data.frame (176x2) where I have only the genes (rownames of the main dataset) and their resulting protein abreviation.

Although there are different 176 genes, most of them results in the same protein so I have 22 different abreviations (row labels).

I would like to group the rows by the protein abreviations.

This is the code I'm running, where `teste` is the main data.frame and `ident` is the identification data.frame:

```
#crio minha paleta de cores do heatmap
my_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("grey92", "green", "red"))(n = 299)
#crio os limites de cada cor 
col_breaks = c(seq(-5.4,-5.3,length=1), # for grey
               seq(-5.2,0,length=219),  # for green
               seq(0.01,11.1,length=80)) #for red

png("D:/Mestrado/PCW/Heatmap/heatmap_teste.png",    # create PNG for the heat map        
    width = 5*400,        # 5 x 300 pixels
    height = 5*500,
    res = 500,            # 300 pixels per inch
    pointsize = 8)        # smaller font size

heatmap.2(teste, 
          col = my_palette, #cores 
          breaks = col_breaks, #limites das cores 
          symbreaks = TRUE, symkey = FALSE, #limites de cores simetricos em 
          key.title = NA, key.ylab = NA, keysize = 1, density.info = "none",
          trace = "none", #sem tracos
          Colv = FALSE, Rowv = TRUE, #sem organizar pelas colunas, apenas por linhas (se quiser o dendro tem que ser TRUE)
          dendrogram = "none", #sem nenhum dendrograma, se tiver (both, row ou column) ele vai reorganizar os pontos
          margins = c(7,7), #margens de baixo, direita
          main = "DEGs by FoldChange", #titulo
          labRow = ident$abrev, #rownames
          cexRow = 0.2, cexCol = 0.4, #tamanho das letras das legendas de colunas e linhas
          srtCol = 0, offsetCol = 0, adjCol = c(0.44,0), #angulacao e posicao da legenda das colunas
          srtRow = 0, offsetRow = -0.9, adjRow = c(0,0) #angulacao e posicao da legenda das linhas
)

dev.off()
```

To be honest I have no idea how to set the order of rows using repeated strings. As they are repeated there's no way to set it as rownames and make the standard row labels. None of the questions I've checked helped me solving it. Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT**

```
> dput(teste)
structure(c(-5.4, -0.6708813033, 1.378061661, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -0.7571104188, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 0.8833872859, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -0.6892789513, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -0.8297914588, -0.6868436186, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -0.7607811156, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -1.01541751, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -0.6409336586, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, 1.143839406, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-0.9523203778, 1.135483862, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 2.196512174, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -1.118763389, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -0.5937832564, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 0.6163008345, -5.4, -5.4, 2.042870229, 
1.803821023, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -0.6816546611, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
1.519633857, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 3.724578472, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -0.996969924, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
1.316517479, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, 2.043820324, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 1.896437041, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -2.458977247, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 3.189582744, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 2.197727272, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 1.069020329, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -1.011282724, -1.720724529, -1.14882796, -5.4, -1.064854931, 
4.102143891, -5.4, 1.661527301, -5.4, 5.095997124, 0.9133722606, 
1.868416916, 1.637004853, -5.4, 3.517522062, 2.083747425, 1.523230573, 
1.849253304, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 0.9306790445, -1.062442899, -1.176330787, 
-2.710491387, -1.480669494, -5.4, -5.4, 0.9777491518, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, 0.7681252032, 0.6301085726, -2.32268854, -5.4, -5.4, -1.289301326, 
-1.494957671, -5.4, -0.7254508759, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 1.221566025, 
-2.95189949, -1.310351167, -0.8732731726, -1.904882379, -0.7041243891, 
-5.4, 1.79437725, -5.4, 0.8258023835, -1.80439866, -5.4, 0.704782973, 
-0.8769026093, 2.484070963, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -2.180854498, -5.4, 
-5.4, -1.197095007, -1.007931409, 5.112664294, -5.4, -1.501190751, 
-1.003861254, -5.4, 3.910890063, -5.4, -1.60542926, -5.4, 0.6487590291, 
1.980346109, 2.109874466, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 1.974534682, -3.175398172, 
0.7552275053, -5.4, 3.107766887, -1.223584334, -5.4, -1.842269446, 
-5.4, -5.4, -2.085803702, -0.7681739662, -1.300722531, 3.835147531, 
1.908263156, -5.4, 0.6782407641, -2.644888972, -5.4, 4.332185749, 
-4.530326955, -5.4, 1.020428394, -0.6811771425, -0.7322498985, 
2.572052542, 1.376113783, -1.427040157, 0.6285386048, 1.549720916, 
0.819878914, -5.4, -1.071249564, -5.4, 3.743034082, 1.413452604, 
1.874095623, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 2.938575443, 1.695867549, -5.4, 
-4.859600416, -5.4, -5.4, 2.550110166, -5.4, 5.839424164, -5.4, 
-5.4, -1.93616625, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -2.422132618, -1.190522506, 
-5.4, 1.820430606, 2.047451812, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -0.6652277929, 
-5.4, -0.6658891661, -3.084467853, 0.7820596037, -5.4, -0.6403401992, 
-5.4, -1.598339219, -5.4, -5.4, -1.042102949, 7.349999276, 11.01747813, 
1.357121165, -5.4, -1.424288179, -5.4, -1.5066184, -1.546833109, 
1.226058904, -3.466153797, -0.9458963861, -5.4, -1.202565609, 
-2.460594779, 0.8392283651, 1.213170547, -5.4, -5.4, 1.89978346, 
-5.4, -5.4, -1.029939997, -5.4, -1.446086401, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-0.6629551241, 4.099016269, 1.085262503, 2.932959589, -5.4, -5.4, 
2.093063487, -5.4, 1.915848274, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -0.9962349794, 
-5.4, -2.10037681, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -0.6210117273, 1.331372413, 
-5.4, 1.975658524, 1.211549921, -1.233471262, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
1.399379313, -5.4, -0.6740016669, -5.4, -1.01124412, -5.4, -2.390943665, 
-5.4, -5.4, 0.8565706577, -2.867120677, -1.35053717, -1.521508746, 
-1.037313268, -1.900548874, 0.6094680988, 1.945517617, -5.4, 
-5.4, -1.952521244, -3.036790929, 0.8413240654, -0.7487997545, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 1.49218976, -2.134296304, 0.6468980522, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, 4.022331637, -0.6822762592, -0.8392739086, -5.4, 
0.6663729783, 3.763703412, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 0.9411168983, -5.4, 
1.205722503, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 2.566157569, -3.110145172, -5.4, 
-5.4, 2.824551349, -0.9101716509, 2.35914329, -5.4, -5.4, 1.330068602, 
-5.4, -1.168802563, -5.4, 4.531656424, 1.193230929, -5.4, -5.4, 
-1.860900372, -5.4, 3.966780341, -5.4, 4.474636821, 2.960770832, 
-5.4, -1.087510462, 2.031218454, -5.4, -3.111368394, 0.6198447009, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 1.409333162, -5.4, -5.4, 
1.534214948, -1.985404448, -5.4, 2.246851864, -0.6085522445, 
-5.4, -0.7825077679, -5.4, 2.819064468, 1.546044754, 5.45071172, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 0.6215479324, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 1.953754509, 
4.111392533, 1.217192143, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -0.6536367475, -5.4, 
-5.4, -1.593053248, 1.272739347, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -2.2094143, 
-5.4, -5.4, -0.9252090744, -5.4, 10.73150153, -5.4, 0.8290287022, 
-1.361527581, -0.7217209107, -5.4, -5.4, 0.9501998031, -1.498026229, 
-5.4, -1.40522647, -0.7726975585, -5.4, 0.6705689582, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, 1.74646153, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
0.694357608, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
1.783182539, -5.4, 0.8308832845, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 3.032451351, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 3.239523326, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 1.760724595, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -0.9189042752, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -2.048912159, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, 1.061778374, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 0.8598045899, -5.4, -5.4, -0.922740647, 
-5.4, -1.142811945, -5.4, -1.08035035, 4.192213438, 1.233850588, 
2.210412903, -5.4, 4.834885409, 0.9480776802, 1.825836912, 2.114830539, 
-5.4, 4.026107714, 2.016130458, 1.478036658, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, 1.187772243, -5.4, -1.058109756, -2.42424694, -2.361846044, 
-5.4, -5.4, 1.079248107, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 0.8574188354, 0.8751229474, 
-1.890357045, -5.4, -5.4, -0.5977094019, -5.4, -5.4, -0.8422891094, 
-5.4, 1.17095774, 1.173785251, 1.249815231, -2.871954831, -2.00499841, 
-0.8239583587, -1.694191205, -5.4, -5.4, 1.810281832, -5.4, 0.7994156775, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -0.9963121533, 1.659822361, -5.4, -2.715670325, 
-5.4, -2.110508416, 0.7158621168, 0.7894392697, -5.4, -5.4, 4.424310347, 
-5.4, -1.632377109, -1.209387343, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -0.9859913276, 
-5.4, 0.7046625975, 1.796654556, 1.658042843, -5.4, -0.7236388412, 
-5.4, 1.98568531, -3.449300335, 0.7456276423, -5.4, 4.026375215, 
-5.4, 2.484859106, -1.644161591, 0.8181133867, 0.8644447512, 
-5.4, -0.6006995013, -0.857653255, 3.358682663, 2.347032519, 
-5.4, 0.7789589063, -2.446329589, 1.690858527, 4.254847228, -4.009045787, 
-5.4, 0.8818386137, -5.4, -5.4, 2.355385654, 2.105381881, -1.299258612, 
0.7601858588, -5.4, 0.9578884572, -5.4, -5.4, -2.449136834, 2.192089436, 
0.9335797681, 2.053549902, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 3.878944011, 1.873728991, 
-5.4, -5.179255352, -5.4, -0.6167480012, -5.4, -5.4, 3.623600045, 
0.7878877467, 0.7268142377, -1.527002397, -0.5992913466, -5.4, 
0.7335243032, -1.960406125, -5.4, -5.4, 2.943339449, 2.657323841, 
2.733839504, 0.7704358606, -5.4, -0.647194463, -3.129150599, 
-5.4, -2.206755605, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 0.6924850632, -5.4, 0.5967840906, 
0.7609795869, -1.100392814, 3.577022964, 9.074809571, 1.812236418, 
-5.4, -1.243123789, -5.4, -1.420592199, -5.4, 1.524302799, -4.001283207, 
-0.9079146004, -1.079043267, -1.061229437, -2.567940513, -5.4, 
1.123194077, 0.7829357937, -5.4, 1.834010837, -5.4, -5.4, -1.028641048, 
-5.4, -1.469574719, -5.4, -5.4, 1.402427256, -0.8254210766, 3.821792519, 
1.110334347, 2.882993624, -5.4, -2.22064757, 2.58667136, -5.4, 
1.858988288, -5.4, -2.162519909, 0.6237718206, -5.4, -5.4, -1.571255273, 
-5.4, -5.4, -1.54719474, -0.5829175255, 1.234230151, -5.4, 2.663153224, 
1.466171852, -1.330471429, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 1.5248916, 1.005234764, 
-5.4, -5.4, -0.6807612469, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 0.8736322162, 
-2.78670184, -2.053482171, -1.478627584, -0.831661332, -1.145778843, 
1.118941048, 1.951889007, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 0.6904523816, 
-0.875736737, -5.4, -1.947390165, -5.4, 1.746835277, -2.068817415, 
0.8987035571, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 3.321984806, -5.4, -0.9765333094, 
-5.4, 0.9436959441, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 0.989733326, -5.4, 
-5.4, -0.9720749183, -5.4, -5.4, 2.562242601, -3.389279321, -5.4, 
0.8544244477, 3.727387944, -5.4, 3.539887618, -5.4, -5.4, 1.623520883, 
-5.4, -1.00623577, -5.4, 4.009756208, 1.62090692, -5.4, -5.4, 
-1.666453244, -5.4, 3.873948501, -5.4, 4.421052529, 2.811600845, 
-5.4, -0.7820419152, 1.801912927, -5.4, -2.990434239, 0.7421884312, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -1.529296347, -5.4, 0.9189101027, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -1.575970477, -5.4, 2.415298572, -0.8763283561, -5.4, 
-0.7036571622, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 3.252009246, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, 0.6037701868, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 5.225556907, 1.814619573, 
2.352877451, -5.4, -5.4, -0.6428722872, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 0.979634222, 
-5.4, 1.157009301, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -0.9902041984, -5.4, 
8.740755939, 0.8953128285, 1.138157962, -1.186046688, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, 1.238333919, -2.034225796, -5.4, -1.668538414, -0.6378353422, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -1.527173422, -1.849005147, -1.171151886, 
-5.4, -5.4, -0.5816710932, -5.4, 2.727173764, -5.4, 1.364994615, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 2.441860943, -5.4, 2.233498248, 1.303446426, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 0.6516369852, -5.4, -1.417670848, 
-2.910890561, -1.712052143, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
0.8240507971, 0.7066771301, -1.678864376, -5.4, -5.4, -1.032925626, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 0.8925829987, 0.7056065538, -2.282143331, 
-1.155465238, -5.4, -1.525091129, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -0.586719217, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 0.5914108523, -5.4, 2.415725237, -5.4, -5.4, 
-1.457894778, -1.36089068, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-1.27101933, -1.066514165, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -1.750710298, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 1.338478945, -2.942607127, 
0.5803367949, -5.4, -5.4, -1.091731099, -5.4, -2.130092057, 0.805826597, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -1.049558793, 2.572260894, 2.061656273, 1.31485788, 
0.7359025216, -1.976612751, 1.870510535, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-0.8812170442, -5.4, 1.580719948, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 1.327739083, 
0.9967058448, -0.7013011397, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 1.058196656, 1.9206526, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 2.422545642, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -1.542041379, -5.4, 0.8913326124, 0.8034806118, -1.816011134, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -1.979761875, -1.387740639, -3.280454578, -5.4, 
1.787150894, 2.74004832, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -3.232009206, -5.4, 
-2.179254416, -5.4, -5.4, -1.342345671, 0.6524310688, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -0.9862688445, 3.965308779, -5.4, 1.38482852, -5.4, -1.205015207, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -3.775247636, -0.9727188025, -5.4, -0.8815881317, 
-2.487155486, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -1.527173422, -1.849005147, -1.171151886, 
-5.4, -5.4, -0.5816710932, -5.4, 2.727173764, -5.4, 1.364994615, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 2.441860943, -5.4, 2.233498248, 1.303446426, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 0.6516369852, -5.4, -1.417670848, 
-2.910890561, -1.712052143, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
0.8240507971, 0.7066771301, -1.678864376, -5.4, -5.4, -1.032925626, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 0.8925829987, 0.7056065538, -2.282143331, 
-1.155465238, -5.4, -1.525091129, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -0.586719217, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 0.5914108523, -5.4, 2.415725237, -5.4, -5.4, 
-1.457894778, -1.36089068, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-1.27101933, -1.066514165, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -1.750710298, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 1.338478945, -2.942607127, 
0.5803367949, -5.4, -5.4, -1.091731099, -5.4, -2.130092057, 0.805826597, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -1.049558793, 2.572260894, 2.061656273, 1.31485788, 
0.7359025216, -1.976612751, 1.870510535, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-0.8812170442, -5.4, 1.580719948, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 1.327739083, 
0.9967058448, -0.7013011397, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 1.058196656, 1.9206526, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 2.422545642, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -1.542041379, -5.4, 0.8913326124, 0.8034806118, -1.816011134, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -1.979761875, -1.387740639, -3.280454578, -5.4, 
1.787150894, 2.74004832, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -3.232009206, -5.4, 
-2.179254416, -5.4, -5.4, -1.342345671, 0.6524310688, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -0.9862688445, 3.965308779, -5.4, 1.38482852, -5.4, -1.205015207, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -3.775247636, -0.9727188025, -5.4, -0.8815881317, 
-2.487155486, -5.4, 0.7792280505, -5.4, -5.4, 1.938460569, 1.297253685, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -2.254931927, -5.4, -0.8089649939, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, 1.055731761, -3.475591227, -5.4, -1.438808968, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 2.833925306, 
-5.4, -5.4, 1.018527805, -5.4, -5.4, 1.057346735, -1.280041913, 
-0.9919286322, -0.8941532811, 1.797270928, 1.800669612, 1.095242155, 
0.6091239711, -5.4, -1.09116174, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -0.982181148, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 0.8610467763, -1.208151571, 1.12947883, 
-5.4, -5.4, -0.7382658493, -5.4, -3.602262995, -5.4, -5.4, -2.488808028, 
-5.4, -5.4, 1.423134723, -5.4, -5.4, -0.7326746102, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -0.744508311, -5.4, 0.9701224159, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -0.6886595657, -5.4, -5.4, 
-1.010072244, 0.8865882392, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 0.7615357175, 
-5.4, -5.4, 0.8742412208, -5.4, -0.7231593892, -5.4, -0.9837437006, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 3.539070967, 1.928558156, 0.9099822222, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -1.689269108, -5.4, -5.4, -0.8556496925, -5.4, 
1.417508495, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -3.511712113, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 1.950338063, -5.4, -5.4, 
-0.7089725182, 1.539223664, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 1.739783051, -5.4, 
3.024689566, 2.285667742, -0.8408134665, -5.4, -0.7349885981, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -1.463734157, 1.441321896, 
-0.7359260856, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -5.4, -0.9136717008, 
0.8166356405, -5.4, -5.4, 1.068844933, -5.4, -5.4, 1.966598868, 
-5.4, -5.4, -5.4, 1.853832412, -5.4), .Dim = c(176L, 10L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("C0vsC12", "C0vsC24", "C0vsT12", "C0vsT24", "C12vsC24", 
    "C12vsT12", "C12vsT24", "C24vsT12", "C24vsT24", "T12vsT24"
    )))
```

```
> dput(ident)
structure(list(gene = structure(1:176, .Label = c("gene10120", 
"gene10247", "gene1032", "gene10377", "gene10467", "gene10529", 
"gene10533", "gene10593", "gene10632", "gene10774", "gene10836", 
"gene10889", "gene10984", "gene11115", "gene11293", "gene11393", 
"gene11453", "gene11454", "gene11456", "gene11458", "gene11696", 
"gene11704", "gene11754", "gene1193", "gene11930", "gene11932", 
"gene11948", "gene11991", "gene12117", "gene12118", "gene12216", 
"gene12218", "gene12343", "gene12359", "gene12413", "gene12584", 
"gene12607", "gene12696", "gene12707", "gene12708", "gene12726", 
"gene12745", "gene12775", "gene12777", "gene12802", "gene12891", 
"gene13023", "gene13024", "gene1303", "gene13050", "gene13051", 
"gene13357", "gene13517", "gene1360", "gene14084", "gene14164", 
"gene14481", "gene14610", "gene147", "gene14718", "gene14736", 
"gene14785", "gene14835", "gene14857", "gene14914", "gene15024", 
"gene15057", "gene15092", "gene15413", "gene15557", "gene15943", 
"gene15998", "gene16066", "gene16174", "gene16303", "gene16406", 
"gene16436", "gene16482", "gene16952", "gene16987", "gene171", 
"gene17454", "gene17502", "gene17545", "gene17689", "gene17696", 
"gene17706", "gene17738", "gene17880", "gene17892", "gene17935", 
"gene17936", "gene17939", "gene1797", "gene18197", "gene18427", 
"gene18596", "gene1982", "gene19957", "gene19959", "gene19960", 
"gene20107", "gene2120", "gene2162", "gene2331", "gene2536", 
"gene2660", "gene2663", "gene2664", "gene2775", "gene2838", "gene2950", 
"gene3084", "gene3087", "gene3336", "gene3486", "gene3830", "gene3877", 
"gene4061", "gene4133", "gene4134", "gene4246", "gene4292", "gene4319", 
"gene4501", "gene4520", "gene4522", "gene4527", "gene4550", "gene4805", 
"gene5066", "gene5145", "gene5207", "gene5293", "gene5336", "gene5468", 
"gene5488", "gene5787", "gene5838", "gene6084", "gene6607", "gene6671", 
"gene6799", "gene6942", "gene699", "gene7019", "gene7049", "gene7205", 
"gene7317", "gene7344", "gene7425", "gene7693", "gene803", "gene841", 
"gene8477", "gene8551", "gene8602", "gene8626", "gene879", "gene8799", 
"gene8913", "gene9058", "gene9059", "gene9085", "gene9153", "gene9155", 
"gene9212", "gene940", "gene9513", "gene957", "gene9649", "gene9661", 
"gene9664", "gene9675", "gene978", "gene9800"), class = "factor"), 
    abrev = structure(c(18L, 13L, 4L, 4L, 13L, 17L, 19L, 15L, 
    10L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 5L, 10L, 6L, 4L, 15L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 
    7L, 7L, 8L, 19L, 10L, 20L, 8L, 19L, 22L, 4L, 9L, 1L, 4L, 
    19L, 1L, 17L, 6L, 11L, 19L, 19L, 22L, 15L, 7L, 17L, 7L, 4L, 
    19L, 13L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 19L, 19L, 2L, 13L, 2L, 13L, 8L, 10L, 
    18L, 19L, 17L, 4L, 13L, 10L, 13L, 19L, 13L, 22L, 4L, 17L, 
    19L, 17L, 13L, 16L, 22L, 22L, 18L, 9L, 7L, 18L, 18L, 13L, 
    18L, 19L, 8L, 4L, 19L, 13L, 22L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 17L, 22L, 
    22L, 13L, 6L, 10L, 21L, 21L, 19L, 6L, 12L, 22L, 17L, 22L, 
    22L, 22L, 4L, 7L, 22L, 22L, 19L, 8L, 17L, 3L, 4L, 22L, 22L, 
    22L, 18L, 19L, 13L, 8L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 4L, 8L, 22L, 
    8L, 11L, 17L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 14L, 3L, 22L, 7L, 13L, 22L, 19L, 
    7L, 17L, 6L, 22L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 13L, 22L, 
    3L, 3L, 6L, 17L, 17L, 13L, 7L, 7L, 13L, 9L, 18L, 10L, 17L, 
    19L, 12L, 9L, 8L, 20L), .Label = c("a-Ara", "a-Gal", "a-Mann", 
    "AGal", "AgluT", "Ara", "B-Gal", "B-GalT", "B-Mann", "Cell", 
    "epi", "fuc", "GalAT", "GluA", "GluT", "MannT", "PG", "PL", 
    "PME", "Rha", "RhamL", "Xyl"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-176L))
```

The image I'm getting: 
[image: heatmap]
(I know it looks awkward - I'm still setting the parameters, 5.4 FoldChanges are actually the way I figured out to put in grey the genes with no expression in respectives comparisson using breaks)

Comment: We don't have any of your data, so we can't run your code, and we can't see any output. The best anyone can do is guess as to what you're working with, what it looks like, and where it's going wrong. See [mcve]

Comment: Sorry, I thought it wasn't necessary as it is just about the code. Anyway, I add the output of dput of both data frames and the image I'm getting.

Comment: One option could be to use `ggplot2` and separate the row groups by facetting. This would require making a new variable for the row groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you can do this quite easily by `ggplot2` facetting. Here's a rough example.

```
dfmat <- cbind(df, scale(mat))

library(reshape2)
meltdf <- melt(dfmat)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(meltdf, aes(x = variable, y = gene, fill = value)) + 
geom_tile() +
facet_grid(abrev ~ ., scales = "free_y", space = "free_y") + theme_minimal() +
scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "red")
```

Note that I haven't taken care to make the labels readable but this could be easily done.

[image]

You could even do

```
ggplot(meltdf, aes(x = variable, y = gene, fill = value)) + geom_tile() +
facet_wrap(abrev ~ ., ncol = 3, scales = "free_y") + theme_minimal() +
scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, amazing. I'll just adapt the code to set all the "-5.4" values to grey. Thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome! Yes, you can set them to NA and both ggplot and heatmap.2 will let you assign an NA colour easily.